# How to hide auto generated properties in doc tab of storybook?

Tags: storybook

I using Storybook 6.4 (with angular framework)
I m trying to hide a property from auto generated doc (the args table of Storybook)

How to do that for the following story

```
export default {
    component: MyComponent,
    decorators: [moduleMetadata({ imports: [AModuleModule] })],
    parameters: {
        controls: { hideNoControlsWarning: true },
    },
} as Meta;
type MyStory = MyComponent;

export const Default: StoryObj<MyStory> = {};
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is possible to control the auto generated output via the argTypes of Meta definition

```
export default {
    component: MyComponent,
    decorators: [moduleMetadata({ imports: [AModuleModule] })],
    parameters: {
        controls: { hideNoControlsWarning: true },
    },
    argTypes: {
       aPropName: { table: { disable: true } },
       anInputName: { control: { disable: true } },
    }

} as Meta<MyComponent>; // Hint: type your meta object to have some code completion from your IDE for argTypes
type MyStory = MyComponent;

export const Default: StoryObj<MyStory> = {};
```

Et voilà :)